# xhost: unable to open display ""

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, ssh, sudo

I'm trying to use the -S method to run a sudo command

```
user@vmi804792:~$ echo ***** | sudo -S -v
```

But I get this error:

```
*****
[sudo] password for user: Error: Can't open display: unix:0

sudo: no password was provided
```

By the way I'm running this from my VPS (ubuntu) through ssh

I even tried to add this to **visudo**:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Even it's not a good practice. but I guess it didn't work, I still have to provide my password for any sudo command.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart but without password

Comment: Please edit your question and provide context and details. Nothing in your question goes into what you're actually trying to do. Don't fall victim to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You should ask about your actual problem, not a proposed solution. I think you're on the wrong path here.